# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'. > java.io.IOException: Failed to delete annotationProcessors.json

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to code in `Kotlin` in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2. When I make changes in the code then I have to rebuild the complete application from Build -> Rebuild Project then Run

After making changes in code, simply when I click on run button then it shows this error randomly.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to delete C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\Kotlin\FirstDemo\app\build\intermediates\javaPrecompile\debug\annotationProcessors.json

What could be the issue ? It seems issue with build-tools or `Kotlin` compiler as it works fine with `Java`.

**Top-Level build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Module level build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.williams.firstdemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Comment: seems like okay. `Clean-Rebuild-Restart` IDE

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it works When I make changes in the code then I have to rebuild the complete application from Build -> Rebuild Project then Run but it should work just from Run

Comment: same problem for `1.1.2-2`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Should we raise a ticket for it ? or it is already there

Comment: You can raise that .